# class file has wrong file version 51.0, should be 49.0

Tags: gwt, compilation

my environment is :

```
windows 7, 32 bit, two jdk, one is 1.5, another is 1.7, google gwt, jetty, ant, two eclipse, one is kepler, another is luna.
```

for kepler, I set its jdk is 1.5, and use ant to compile and jar, this works, and eclipse can open the gwt window when debugging.

then i use luna, check out project(gwt project) from cvs, there is error said the jdk is 1.5 when compiling with ant, therefore I changed the jdk to 1.7 since this project requires this version, eventually compile is ok with ant.  However, when I debug it in eclipse, it opens a gwt window said unable to compile to jsp, and the error in console is :

```
10:20:48.193 [btpool0-8] ERROR org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler - Javac exception

Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:933)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:382)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:439)  

.....
10:20:48.194 [btpool0-8] ERROR org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler - Env: Compile:

javaFileName=/C:/Users/FRANKH~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Jetty_localhost_8001_www__Login__-wcglsc/jsp//org/apache/jsp\login_jsp.java

cannot access cn.com.yict.easyport.web.service.CommonUtil

wrong class file： D:\cvs\eInvoice\common-web\target\classes\cn\com\yict\easyport\web\service\CommonUtil.class

class file has wrong version 51.0, should be 49.0

please delete this file or make sure ...

import cn.com.yict.easyport.web.service.CommonUtil;
```

what happened?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modified this file : org.eclipse.jdt.launching.prefs under : .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings,

this problem has been fixed.

The modification is : 
 add

```
<libraryLocations>\r\n<libraryLocation 
jreJar\="D\:/Java/jdk7/jre/lib/resources.jar" 
jreJavadoc\="http\://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/" 
jreSrc\="D\:/Java/jdk7/src.zip" pkgRoot\=""/>\r\n.........
```

to it.

eclipse is :

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600
```

my questions are :

1. what is this file used for?
2. when use this file?
3. why I have to add these information to it by hand rather than generate these automatically when I set jdk in eclipse preference?
4. why this error occur if this file doesn't has  when running project(the project compile success before running)?

Comment: If you have additional questions, please post a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)